# How to loop the mysql procedures?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have table_a which have these following records:

```
+----+---+---+
| a  | b | c |
+----+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 2 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 |
|  3 | 1 | 2 |
|  4 | 1 | 2 |
|  5 | 1 | 2 |
|  6 | 1 | 2 |
|  7 | 1 | 2 |
|  8 | 1 | 2 |
|  9 | 1 | 2 |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |
+----+---+---+
```

How can I add another column(`d`) which the number of records are only 4 wherein the value are the product of loop statement? I'm using mysql stored procedure for this kind of sql.

These are the output that I wanted to make

```
+----+---+---+---+
| a  | b | c | d |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
|  2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
|  3 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
|  4 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
|  5 | 1 | 2 |   |
|  6 | 1 | 2 |   |
|  7 | 1 | 2 |   |
|  8 | 1 | 2 |   |
|  9 | 1 | 2 |   |
| 10 | 1 | 2 |   |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Why would you use a "loop" in stored procedure to obtain the specified result? I can't see any sensible reason for implementing a stored procedure to do this.

Comment: Because I will set a parameter for this....

Comment: Like I said, no sensible reason. I don't see anywhere you've specified providing a parameter. For what? The name of the column to be returned? The number of rows you want numbered? You could just as easily, more easily actually, specify a value in a SQL statement, than all the rigmarole of passing a parameter value to a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the results just by doing:

```
select a, b, c, (case when a <= 4 then a end) as d
from table t;
```

You can add the column and set the value as:

```
alter table add column d unsigned;

update table t
    set d = a
    where d <= a;
```

I see no need to loop in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

on a side note if the values inside of b are something other than 1 and this is just for an example then you can do multiplication like so

```
SELECT a, b, c, IF(@a <= 4, a * b, '') as d, @a := @a + 1
FROM table_a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := 1) t
```

or to make it easier if column a is an incrementing id then just use a like so

```
SELECT a, b, c, IF(a <= 4, a * b, '') as d
FROM table_a
```